# Failed to connect to repository : org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: not authorized

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to set up a jenkins pipeline and I get this error message:

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hVB.png)

Why is this happening? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you can manually checkout repositories on your Jenkins node you probably need to do one or more of the following:

- Re-enter your credential to make sure you entered them right
- Add the Jenkins node's public key to your [user's authorized keys](https://github.com/settings/keys)